# Laravel insert data array to database

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this line of codes at my **`Controller`** to get data from google analytics

```
$analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(Period::days(30),
    'ga:',
    [
        'metrics' => 'ga:users,ga:newUsers,ga:sessions,ga:sessionsPerUser,ga:pageviews,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:bounceRate',
        'start-date' => '2018-08-01',
        'end-date' => '2018-09-02',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle',
    ]);
```

When I `dd($analyticsData);` This is what I got.

[image: analytics]

This is my migration query.

```
    Schema::create('analytics', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('site_id');
        $table->string('site_url');
        $table->integer('report_id');
        $table->integer('analytics_view_id'); 
        $table->date('reportGenerated');
        $table->integer('gaUsers');
        $table->integer('gaNewUsers');
        $table->integer('gaSessions');
        $table->integer('gaSessionsPerUser');
        $table->integer('gaPageviews');
        $table->integer('gaPageviewsPerSession');
        $table->integer('gaAvgSession');
        $table->integer('gaBounceRate');

    });
```

Now my problem is how can I able to stores those array data to my database? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
$model = Analytics::create([
   'gaUsers' => $analyticsData['ga:users'],
   'gaNewUsers' => $analyticsData['ga:newUsers'],
   // ... and so on...
]);
```

Just in case make sure you have those fields in `$fillable` attribute of your `Analytics` model.

Comment: Thanks now I will make my model as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$analytic = new Analytics();

$analytic->gaUsers = $analyticsData['ga:users'];
$analytic->gaNewUsers = $analyticsData['ga:newUsers'];
...
$analytic->save();
```

Comment: Sorry, it won't work. $analyticsData is array, and object properties cannot have colon

Comment: It would be fine now.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I had some data that needs to pull from other tables. and save it to my analytics table as well is it okay if I use this line of commands? Like for example I need to pull my site_url from sites table.

Comment: @GihanLakshan how do you think?

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin i'm not clear what you're asking

Comment: @GihanLakshan like if my `$url = 'google'` how can I stored it to my database in `$table->string('site_url');` using your code?

Comment: simply use `$analytic->site_url = $url;`

Comment: glad to help you